Per the Midrash - how can Hashem make it rain on Shabbat
Per the midrash quoted in this answer, Hashem keeps all commandments, if so how does the midrash explain why Hashem makes it rain on Shabbat wouldn't that be a Zoreia - Sowing
See Rambam Hilchot Shabbat 8:2

אֲבָל הַמַּשְׁקֶה צְמָחִין וְאִילָנוֹת בְּשַׁבָּת הֲרֵי זֶה תּוֹלֶדֶת זוֹרֵעַ וְחַיָּב בְּכָל שֶׁהוּא.
In contrast, watering plants and trees on the Sabbath is considered merely a derivative of sowing


Please be aware that Hashem is real, and this world is a mashal, an absolute nothing. Whatever it means to do zoreia for real, we don't know, but we can assume that He keeps that mitzva "on His level" so to speak.

@RabbiKaii i don't disagree, my question is how the midrash would interpret it, given that it went as far as explaining how Hashem carries.

If you set up (before Shabbat) an irrigation system to run on a timer is that a problem?

You should apply this to other things to: How come stars can be born on Shabbat? That’s kindling fire-plasma! How can wind work? It cleans things! How can earthquakes happen? That’s demolishing! Rain and wind put out fires!   If you can question this, you’d also have to question the rest of the universe. How can Hashem do anything on Shabbat?

@QwertyCTRL.  terrific questions, given that i was asked about rain i wanted to address that

@JoelK yes, see https://outorah.org/p/50824/ "On erev Shabbos, it is permitted to turn on a water sprinkling system and allow it to continue watering the grass during Shabbos.75 It is also permitted to allow the automated sprinkling system, which is preset in advance to turn on and off at a specific time every night, to continue operating on Shabbos and Yom as well"

@RabbiKaii would love to see a sefer discussing this.

@Yoreinu in which case you may have your answer

@JoelK what if it starts raining on shabbat

@Yoreinu at what point in time did Hashem act so that it would rain on Shabbat?

@JoelK that's a very good point!
